# Selenium WebDriver with C# reduce connection time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, selenium

I am developing a project for the web WhatsApp. Sample codes are available below. When I redirect the url, the link is about 7-8 seconds. I see some sample applications and instant connection is provided. What do I need to do for this?

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    driveri.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://web.whatsapp.com"); 
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    timer1.Start(); 
} 

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    driveri.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=xxxxx&text=xxxxx"); 
    Thread.Sleep(5000);
    driveri.FindElement(By.ClassName("_35EW6")).Click();  
    driveri.Manage().Cookies.DeleteAllCookies();
}
```

Comment: Which are these `sample applications` and `instant connection`? Where do you see them? What do you want to do with them?

Comment: .GoToUrl section of the link. It waits at least 7-8 seconds at the moment of connection. But there are applications that exceed this expectation. I could not

Comment: What is the sequence order of your script ? I mean execution order.

Comment: there is no different command. I wrote all of them